# How to convert Delphi TDateTime to String with microsecond precision

Tags: delphi, datetime

I need to convert a `TDateTime` to a `String` with **microsecond** precision.
In case of millisecond precision it is possible to use formatting:

```
DateTimeToString(Result, 'd.m.yyyy hh:nn:ss.zzz', dateTime);
```

but I need three more digits (microseconds).

It is possible to take the fractional part and divide it by 1/86400/1000000 but I'm looking for more efficient way to convert it.

Comment: Many of the date/time functions will yield values that are only accurate to the millisecond level. Where are your values coming from? Are you sure that `TDateTime` is the right data type for your needs?

Comment: The only obvious efficiency here is to multiply the fractional part by `86400000000` instead of using division by the recprocal.  I'm not sure how much simpler or efficient it can get, to be honest.  Conversion to string is going to be by far the slowest part of this, if this is in a performance bottleneck.

Comment: @David: I need to store and convert different time values from datafiles parsing or our measuring equipments. There microseconds exists. Resolution of the TDateTime format is cca 10 microseconds if it holds current year (it is better if just fractions are used).

Comment: It depends on where the data came from originally. And how it's been processed. If your data has microseconds fine. But then I can't understand what's hard about a single multiplication. Personally I'd look for a data type not based on floating point values. You really want a 64 bit integer.

Comment: Consider also that `DateTime` types don't typically have helper methods that resolve to microseconds because most of the time this really doesn't make any sense.  Even though a `double` based `DateTime` format has the *resolution* to represent microsecond values, the values themselves are almost invariably coming from non real-time systems where the *precision* of the value is simply not there.  When such values *are* coming from real-time hardware, you would really be best served by another data format, as @DavidHeffernan suggested.

Comment: You know the answer already, there are no better way. `TDateTime` haven't designed for microsec precision and naturally have no corresponding format specifier for that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The accuracy of a date-time varies depending how far away from *"zero"* you are.

A Delphi `TDateTime` is actually an 8-byte floating point `Double`, with zero being `12/30/1899 12:00:00 am`.

We can figure out the precision of a `TDateTime` by incrementing the floating point datetime by the smallest quantum possible:

```
function AddQuantumToDateTime(const dt: TDateTime): TDateTime;
var
   overlay: Int64 absolute Result;
begin
   Result := dt;
   overlay := overlay+1;
end;
```

With this, we can figure out the smallest increment that a `TDateTime` can even **handle**. It varies with the date being used, as the further you are from zero, the larger the quantum amount is:

- **12/31/1899**: ±0 ns
- **1/1/1900**: ±0 ns
- **1/1/1970**: ±314 ns
- **1/1/2000**: ±629 ns
- **1/1/2016**: ±629 ns
- **1/1/2038**: ±629 ns
- **1/1/3000**: ±5,029 ns
- **1/1/4000**: ±10,058 ns
- **1/1/5000**: ±20,117 ns
- **1/1/6000**: ±20,117 ns
- **1/1/7000**: ±20,117 ns
- **1/1/8000**: ±40,233 ns
- **1/1/9000**: ±40,233 ns
- **1/1/9999**: ±40,233 ns

So for the time being, a DateTime **can** give you a resolution of about half a microsecond.

While the Windows [`FILETIME` structure does support a resolution of 100ns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), [the `SYSTEMTIME` structure only supports down to the millisecond](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724950(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
typedef struct _SYSTEMTIME {
  WORD wYear;
  WORD wMonth;
  WORD wDayOfWeek;
  WORD wDay;
  WORD wHour;
  WORD wMinute;
  WORD wSecond;
  WORD wMilliseconds;
} SYSTEMTIME, *PSYSTEMTIME;
```

Microsoft SQL Server's new `datetime2(7)` returns datetime strings with up to seven digit (100 ns) of fractional second accuracy:

```
SELECT CAST('20160802' AS datetime2(6)) AS TheNow

TheNow
==========================
2016-08-02 00:00:00.000000
```

Your question then is how to convert a `TDateTime` to a string that contains microsecond (billionths of a second) precision. You already have your answer:

```
function DateTimeToStrUs(dt: TDatetime): string;
var
    us: string;
begin
    //Spit out most of the result: '20160802 11:34:36.'
    Result := FormatDateTime('yyyymmdd hh":"nn":"ss"."', dt);

    //extract the number of microseconds    
    dt := Frac(dt); //fractional part of day
    dt := dt * 24*60*60; //number of seconds in that day
    us := IntToStr(Round(Frac(dt)*1000000));

    //Add the us integer to the end:
    // '20160801 11:34:36.' + '00' + '123456'
    Result := Result + StringOfChar('0', 6-Length(us)) + us;
end;
```

Where:

```
DateTimeToStrUs(Now)
```

Returns:

> 20160802 11:34:36.482364

Comment: The zero date in Delphi is actually 1899-12-30 (not 31). And in your calculated TDateTime's precision in function of the year, starting from year 3000 it's milliseconds (ms), not nanoseconds. Good example of the use of "absolute" though.

Comment: If you try    dt := EncodeDate(2022, 05, 11) + EncodeTime(6, 55, 05, 0);
  s := DateTimeToStrUs(dt); you get 20220511 06:55:05.1000000 . So correct is  us := IntToStr(Round(Frac(dt)*1000000) mod 100000);